# Any way to make reflection not bypass Groovy interceptors (invokeMethod)?

Tags: groovy, reflection, metaclass

I've got a class that is wrapping objects with a proxy using Groovy's metaClass "getProperty" and "invokeMethod" methods. The proxy/wrapper lets me do lazy loading on the objects, only grab the data once the getter for a property has been called.

It works well when I actually use the getters, but I ran into a problem when I started trying to use Jackson to serialize the object (a secondary use case). I thought that Jackson would spin through all of the getter methods, which would invoke each of the getters and load all the data. But unlike when I call getters myself, when Jackson uses reflection to call the methods, my interceptor methods are not invoked, so all my data is still null.

I trace the call to my object in the Jackson library to [this bit of code](https://github.com/joansmith/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanPropertyWriter.java#L633) in the BeanPropertyWriter. The `_accessorMethod.invoke(bean)` call invokes the 'getter' method, but not the code in my proxy. I was able to recreate it in a unit test too outside of Jackson too.

Is there something I should implement in my Groovy proxy class that would capture those requests via the Method objects in reflection?

This is what my proxying code looks like:

```
static <T> T lazyProxyFor(T object) {
    Class clazz = object.class
    object.metaClass.getProperty = { String name ->
        println "getting property $name"

        def currentVal = clazz.metaClass.getMetaProperty(name).getProperty(delegate)
        if (!currentVal) {
          setProperty('testing') //normally this goes and gets data from my service
        }
        return currentVal
    }

    object.metaClass.invokeMethod = { String name, Object args ->
        println "calling $name"

        if (name ==~ /get[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/ && args?.size() == 0) {
            object[name.drop(3).uncapitalize()] // call the getProperty method
        } else {
            clazz.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)?.invoke(delegate, args) //like the underlying object process the 
        }
    }

    return object
}
```

and this is the code I was testing with:

```
Address address = lazyProxyFor(Address)

address.class.declaredMethods.each{ method ->
    if (method.name.startsWith('get')) {
        method.invoke(address)    //<-- if I run with this version I get no output

        //address."$method.name"()  //<-- if I run with this version I get two messages, one for each 
                                    //getter method and then the underlying property, presummably because
                                    //groovy is more involved here, instead of reflection
    }
}
```

Comment: lazyProxyFor should return instance of GroovyObject so, you could use groovy invokeMethod: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyObject.html#invokeMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)

Comment: Well, the Address object (sorry, not included in the post) is a POGO, which is an extension of the GroovyObject. Which I think is why calling the getters directly works as I expected, and hits the invokeMethod logic.

Comment: No way to activate groovy interceptor for java reflection call. Think about implementing java proxy object.

Comment: Thanks for confirming - that definitely matches my experience, just wanted someone else to double check me in case there was some trick that I was missing. Appreciate the help.